# php error_log() archive log files

Tags: php, logging

I have a cron script that outputs errors using `error_log()`. Sometimes, however, the log file can attain a large size. Does `error_log()` have native functions that automatically archive the log file after reaching a certain defined number of lines? I can write my own function to check the log file, but I would prefer using some native functions if there are any.

Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: @hakre: just to let you know, that is most likely the answer to OP's question, so you should post that as an answer.  The true answer is of course "No", but your answer would be more helpful than that.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by default PHP offers these settings: [Error Handling Runtime Configuration<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

You might want to setup a [*logrotator*](https://serverfault.com/q/343001/69499) on your system, normally done with a cron task or daemon.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it's a good reference for future setup. thx again